# Should untrue answers be flagged/deleted/edited?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/49425/34364).

It states an untrue statement in which, I think, was in a joking manor.

What should I do when I see an answer like this?

Comment: As a general guideline: Before doing _anything_ regarding the answer, check the question. Bad answers are almost always a result of terrible questions, and if that's the case we should deal with the question first. In this instance the question is borderline (imho), and it would be preferable if we find a way to make it better first, and then deal with its answers.

Comment: WTF MAN?! Is it pile up on the Morons Day? ..Calling me out on joke a made a year ago.. *smh*

Comment: @Morons: I was going through the review list and I happened to come across it. Sorry if this bothers you, just wanted to know what to do...

Comment: @Jae NP, where is the Review list?

Comment: @Morons: Top of the screen next to your badges and rep.

Comment: @Morons Don't be hatin' on Jae, he is just working towards that Excavator badge ;-)

Comment: @Maple its all good, he cost me 100 rep points, *i had to say something*.

Comment: @maple_shaft: No... I just like messin with people :P.

Comment: @Morons: Once again, sorry about that. Now don't mention it again ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The reasons for flagging an answer:

- It's not an answer. It makes no attempt to answer the original question. It could be a comment or clarification that should be merged into the original question or added to the original question.
- It's spam. It's advertising something with only promotion. If it's something that legitimately helps the person asking the question, there should be disclosure if the provider is associated with the thing linked to.
- It's abusive or offensive to other members of the community.
- It's otherwise suspicious and a moderator should look at it in more depth.

A wrong answer is not a reason to flag an answer. Wrong answers should not be flagged just because they are wrong. Leave a comment asking for references or providing a reputable reference that disproves the answer and downvote as appropriate.

Note that I deleted the provided answer since it wasn't an answer to the question. It was an attempt to be funny, and pretty much failed. If it was a comment, I would have left it alone, but I didn't feel that it added any value, so rather than migrating it to a comment, I just removed it entirely.

Answer (score 6):

Your choice are (as ever)

- Leave a comment
- Down-vote

If the answer has a negative score and you have more than 20K reputation then you can vote to delete.

What you shouldn't do is flag for moderator attention unless it clearly doesn't answer the question.

In this case it *could* be an answer (albeit a wrong one) - so there is always going to be a judgement call as to which side of the line it lies.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The answer was deleted (I don't know by who) but I will use this for future reference.

Comment: @Jae - looks like another moderator agreed that it wasn't a real answer.

Comment: I looked at it. It made 0 attempt to answer the question - it struck me as a pure attempt at humor. I have no problems with humor, as long as the content also provides a legitimate answer to the question.